# Android studio - how to see APK file in project view

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to see the output folder itself directly in the android studio IDE.

To be clear i want the apk output folder to show up in my IDE so i can see apks as they are built.  The folder from the OS explorer shows the apk in `Foo/*/build/outputs/apk/` .

However, i want this same folder to appear in the IDE. Is it possible ? This way after a build it would be easier to get the apk and its also a good indicator when the build process is complete.

Here is what the IDE UI currently looks like, notice how its missing any output folder:
[image]

Comment: Release builds or debug?

Comment: Yeah I've noticed this as well. I believe it's being intentionally filtered out somewhere, but I've not yet been able to find out where.

Comment: Release. but also debug should be the same.